# Can't connect to hbase with service in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, hbase, hbase-client

I have installed hbase cluster with helm following https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/gradiant/hbase

with this command: `helm install my-hbase gradiant-bigdata/hbase --create-namespace -n hbase`

That is installed and running and its service name is `my-hbase-hbase-master` in namespace `hbase` I'm setting `config.set("hbase.masters", "my-hbase-hbase-master.hbase.svc.cluster.local:16000")` but that is not working getting connection error.
I also tried forwarding port on 16000 and connect that with `localhost:16000` that is also not working.

I'm connecting with java client.

```
val config = HBaseConfiguration.create()
config.set("hbase.masters", "my-hbase-hbase-master.hbase.svc.cluster.local:16000")
ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config)
```

Comment: Can you check if your `hbase-master` pods are running?

Comment: yes everything running fine except can't connect with service but can use `hbase shell` on `hbase-master.`